# Not using CONNECT for SSL with Squid proxy

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, ssl, squid

I want to disable encryption between my browser and my Squid so that I can get Squid to cache the pages. As using my own server and SSH port forw I'm not that worried about security.

I already tried using SSL/TLS setup with Squid/Chrome but after finally getting it to work the only result was CONNECT requests over SSL/TLS.

Is there any way to disable CONNECT in Firefox/Chrome or other good suggestions ?